# Sending JSON to a webservice using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

what modifications should i do in following code in order to post multiple values from form to my web service in form of json string ?

I have tried this as-

```
  <script>

    function ajaxRequest(){
        var  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
             xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
                 alert(xmlhttp.readyState);
                }
                };
                var namevalue=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("name").value);
              //  var fname=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("lastname"));
                var parameters="name="+namevalue
                var url="http://localhost:41191/test/resources/postservice";
            xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            xmlhttp.send(parameters)

   }
</script>
```

Also Using-

```
    function ajaxRequest(){
        var  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
             xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
                 alert(xmlhttp.readyState);
                }
                };

var parameters = { "name": $('#name').val(), "firstname": $('#fname').val() };
                var url = 'http://localhost:41191/test/resources/storeincompleteform';
                xmlhttp.open('POST', url, true);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
                xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(parameters)); }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var parameters = { param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2' };
var url = 'http://localhost:41191/test/resources/postservice';
xmlhttp.open('POST', url, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(parameters));
```

This will send the following data in the POST request body:

```
{"name":"value1","name2":"value2"}
```

The `JSON.stringify` method is natively built into modern browsers but if you want to support some legacy browsers you could reference the [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) script.

Comment: Also, you should consider looking at [YepNope.js](http://yepnopejs.com/) in order to only load json2.js to browsers where it's actually needed, and save bandwidth in the case of browsers that have native support for it.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki, could you be a little more expressive when saying `not working`? Did you try to inspect the AJAX request in your javascript debugging tool? Was the request sent? What did the server respond? Also I am noticing that you have specified an absolute address in your url parameter but you should be aware of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction that's built into browsers and which prevents you from sending cross domain AJAX request. I hope that this is not your case but make sure that you have checked this aspect as well.

Comment: The second that i posted..its takes values from a text box..i am trying to insert this values into the database but it is not working

Comment: I have an alert after the POST request .It shows a message but nothing is happening

Comment: Did you verify if the server side script is hit? What about the same origin policy?